# Array Not Filling Properly

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to deconstruct a document into its respective paragraphs, and input each paragraphs, as a string, into an array. However, each time a new value is added, it overwrites all previous values in the array. The last "paragraph" read (as denoted by newline) is the value of each non-null value of the array.

Here is the code:

```
char buffer[MAX_SIZE];
char **paragraphs = (char**)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
int pp = 0;
int i;

FILE *doc;
doc = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
assert(doc);

while((i = fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), doc) != NULL)) {
    if(strncmp(buffer, "\n", sizeof(buffer))) {
        paragraphs[pp++] = (char*)buffer;
    }
}

printf("pp: %d\n", pp);

for(i = 0; i < MAX_SIZE && paragraphs[i] != NULL; i++) {
    printf("paragraphs[%d]: %s", i, paragraphs[i]);
}
```

The output I receive is:

```
pp: 4
paragraphs[0]: paragraph four
paragraphs[1]: paragraph four
paragraphs[2]: paragraph four
paragraphs[3]: paragraph four
```

when the program is run as follows: `./prog.out doc.txt`, where doc.txt is:

```
paragraph one
paragraph two
paragraph three

paragraph four
```

The behavior of the program is otherwise desired. The paragraph count works properly, ignoring the line that contains ONLY the newline character (line 4).

I assume the problem occurs in the while loop, however am unsure how to remedy the problem.

Comment: With `paragraphs[pp++] = (char*)buffer`: you are only setting each entry in `paragraphs` to point to `buffer`.

Comment: You never allocate memory for `paragraph[i]...`, only for `**paragraph`, you do not need to cast the return value of `malloc()`, and you are never calling `fclose()`.  There may be others, but start with these and turn on your debugger.

Comment: Because you are using `fgets()`, you are reading _lines_, not _paragraphs_ from your file.  The format of _paragraphs_ in your input file will determine what you have to do to programmatically _recognize_ a paragraph.  For example, read entire file into a single buffer, then parse through looking for successive `\n` characters.  ***fgets()***: _Reads characters from the specified input stream into a lineBuffer until end-of-file is encountered, a newline character is read, or (number_ofChars - 1) characters are read. The newline character is retained._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is pretty sound. Your Paragraph array is supposed to hold each paragraph, and since each paragraph element is just a small 4 bytes pointer you can afford to define a reasonable max number of them. However, since this max number is a constant, it is of little use to allocate the array dynamically.
The only meaningful use of dynamic allocation would be to read the whole text once to count the actual number of paragraphs, allocate the array accordingly and re-read the whole file a second time, but I doubt this is worth the effort.
The downside of using fixed-size paragraph array is that you must stop filling it once you reach the maximal number of elements.
You can then re-allocate a bigger array if you absolutely want to be able to process the whole Bible, but for an educational exercise I think it's reasonable to just stop recording paragraphs (thus producing a code that can store and count paragraphs *up to a maximal number*).

The real trouble with your code is, you don't store the paragraph contents anywhere. When you read the actual lines, it's always inside the same buffer, so each paragraph will point to the same string, which will contain the last paragraph read.

The solution is to make a unique copy of the buffer and have the current paragraph point to that.

C being already messy enough as it is, I suggest using the `strdup()` function, which ***dup***licates a ***str***ing (basically computing string length, allocating sufficient memory, copying the string into it and returning the new block of memory holding the new copy). You just need to remember to free this new copy once you're done using it (in your case at the end of your program).

This is *not* the most time-efficient solution, since each string will require a `strlen` and a `malloc` performed internally by `strdump` while you could have pre-allocated a big buffer for all paragraphs, but it is certainly simpler and probably more memory-efficient (only the minimal amount of memory will be allocated for each string, though each `malloc` consumes a few extra bytes for internal allocator housekeeping).

The bloody awkward `fgets` also stores the trailing `\n` at the end of the line, so you'll probably want to get rid of that.

Your last display loop would be simpler, more robust and more efficient if you simply used pp as a limit, instead of checking uninitialized paragraphs.

Lastly, you'd better define two different constants for max line size and max number of paragraphs. Using the same value for both makes little sense, unless you're processing perfectly square texts :).

```
#define MAX_LINE_SIZE   82 // max nr of characters in a line (including trailing \n and \0)
#define MAX_PARAGRAPHS 100 // max number of paragraphs in a file

void main (void)
{
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_SIZE];
    char * paragraphs[MAX_PARAGRAPHS];
    int pp = 0;
    int i;

    FILE *doc;
    doc = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    assert(doc != NULL);

    while((fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), doc) != NULL)) {
        if  (pp != MAX_PARAGRAPHS  // make sure we don't overflow our paragraphs array
          && strcmp(buffer, "\n")) {
            // fgets awkwardly collects the ending \n, so get rid of it
            if (buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] == '\n') buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';
            // current paragraph references a unique copy of the actual text
            paragraphs[pp++] = strdup (buffer);
        }
    }

    printf("pp: %d\n", pp);

    for(i = 0; i != pp; i++) {
        printf("paragraphs[%d]: %s", i, paragraphs[i]);
        free(paragraphs[i]); // release memory allocated by strdup
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*What is the proper way to allocate the necessary memory? Is the malloc on line 2 not enough?*

No, you need to allocate memory for the 2D array of strings you created. The following will not work as coded.

```
char **paragraphs = (char**)malloc(MAX_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
```

***If you have:***  (for a simple explanation)
    char **array = {0}; //array of C strings, before memory is allocation

Then you can create memory for it like this:

```
int main(void) 
{
    int numStrings = 10;// for example, change as necessary
    int maxLen = MAX_SIZE; //for example, change as necessary
    char **array  {0};
    array = allocMemory(array, numStrings, maxLen);
    //use the array, then free it
    freeMemory(array, numStrings);
    return 0;
}

char ** allocMemory(char ** a, int numStrings, int maxStrLen)
{
    int i;
    a = calloc(sizeof(char*)*(numStrings+1), sizeof(char*));
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
    {
      a[i] = calloc(sizeof(char)*maxStrLen + 1, sizeof(char));
    }
    return a;
}

void freeMemory(char ** a, int numStrings)
{
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<numStrings; i++)
        if(a[i]) free(a[i]);
    free(a);
}
```

***Note:*** you can determine the number of lines in a file several ways, One way for example, by FILE *fp = fopen(filepath, "r");, then calling `ret = fgets(lineBuf, lineLen, fp)` in a loop until `ret == EOF`, keeping count of an index value for each loop. Then `fclose()`.  (which you did not do either)  This necessary step is *not* included in the code example above, but you can add it if that is the approach you want to use.

***Once you have memory allocated***, Change the following in your code:

```
paragraphs[pp++] = (char*)buffer;
```

To:

```
strcpy(paragraphs[pp++], buffer);//no need to cast buffer, it is already char *
```

Also, do not forget to call `fclose()` when you are finished with the open file.

Comment: If this is the approach you're going to take, you need to allocate some memory for those additional strings. Currently `paragraphs` is a `char **` pointing to an uninitialized block of memory big enough to hold the `char *`s

Comment: What is the proper way to allocate the necessary memory? Is the malloc on line 2 not enough?

Comment: You are actually allocating `MAXSIZE` pointers to chars, which is probably not what you want. I guess you need two different constraints here - the paragraph size (which is `MAXSIZE`, I guess), and number of paragraphs. Then your `paragraphs` would be allocated to `MAXSIZE` times number of paragraphs.

Comment: @WumpusQ.Wumbley -  Yes, you are right. My original aim was to address only the copy method, but edited to include memory allocation for an array of multiple strings.